# How to hide terminal window by command on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, command

We create the swift program for run our .jar file.

Our command codes for run .jar file is 'java -jar [jar file's path]',
and run program was fine.

But, after running jar file, the terminal was existed and opend.
If user do close the terminal, also the program running by jar file was closed, too.

We want(we need) 'hide' or 'minimize' the terminal after launch jar file by command...
How can do this...?

Thank you for read my question, and appreciate for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I run the jar file by background('&' width command)

then, run command 'disown'

It was make the seperated between jar file process abd terminal process.

Terminal can close without jar program killed.